# cambiar de idioma zabbix-server usando docker

Tags: docker-compose

Tengo un problema estoy tratando de cambiar el idioma de zabbix en español usando docker pero no lo e conseguido e estado investigando los ejemplos que e encontrado esta el apache2 y en docker si alguien me podría a ayudar o guiar como cambiar el idioma de zabbix en docker estaria muy agradecido 
abajo dejo mi código que funciona bien.

de docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zabbix-db:
    image: monitoringartist/zabbix-db-mariadb
    volumes:
      - zabbix-db-storage:/var/lib/mysql
      - backups:/backups
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=zabbix
      - MARIADB_PASS=my_password
  zabbix-server:
    image: monitoringartist/dockbix-xxl:latest
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "10051:10051"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    links:
      - zabbix-db:zabbix.db
    environment:
      - ZS_DBHost=zabbix.db
      - ZS_DBUser=zabbix
      - ZS_DBPassword=my_password
volumes:
  zabbix-db-storage:
    driver: local
  backups:
    driver: local
```

agradeceria mucho la ayuda de esta comunidad hermosa comunidad 
dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer en docker: 

https://clouding.io/kb/como-instalar-y-configurar-zabbix/

Comment: ya solucione mi problema   estos son los pasos que se   
docker exec -i -t zabbix_zabbixserver  /bin/bash

zabbix_zabbixserver Es el nombre de contenedor

después de entrar en el contenedor debe a parecer ssimilar a esto [root@b3ff8df78721 /]# esto significa que ya estamos en dentro del contenedor 
estando ahi dentro volvemos a entrar en el directorio siguiente:
cd  /usr/local/src/zabbix/frontends/php/include/
estando en ese directorio podemos lista lo que contiene el directorio include con el tipico ls  
buscamos locales.inc.php lo ejecutamos vi locales.inc.php

Comment: i se abrira i buscamos  function getLocales() { donde nos mostrara los idiomas activados buscamos el que dise 'es_ES' => ['name' => _('Spanish (es_ES)'),     'display' => false],
en donde dise display lo cambiamos a (true) 'es_ES' => ['name' => _('Spanish (es_ES)'),     'display' => true],  lo guardamos  en docker no es necesario reiniciar  en mi caso yo no lo reinicie solo recargamos la pagina de zabbix listo ya debe aparecer Español(es_E)  para alguien que tenga el mismo problema que yo....

Answer (score 0):

yo hice:

```
sudo docker cp 8aa379e972:/usr/share/zabbix/include/locales.i
nc.php ./locales.inc.php
```

modifique el **locales.inc.php **

```
sudo docker cp ./locales.inc.php 8aa379e972:/usr/share/zabbix/include/locales.i
nc.php

docker exec -u root f2090464edd2 locale-gen es_ES
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  es_ES.ISO-8859-1... done
Generation complete.

docker restart f2090464edd2
f2090464edd2
```

El tema es que es una traducción "parcial al 60%"

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).